# How to switch buffers (prev & next) with minimal buffer list order modification?

Tags: buffers, window, frames, navigation, buffer-list

How to switch buffers (prev & next) with minimal buffer list order modification?

To be succinct and without getting into the weeds of particular details, the best way to explain what I am trying to do is through a simple example. Given a list of already open buffers, I want to have the following results for buffer-list arrangement as I navigate by `previous-buffer` and/or `next-buffer`.

Initial buffer list (* = currently displayed buffer)

```
HelloWorld.txt
* App.js
init.el
ComplexObjectFactory.java
some-elisp.el
AnotherFile.txt
<more_files_here>
```

When I hit my keybind for `previous-buffer` (or whatever custom function needs to be bound instead):

```
HelloWorld.txt
App.js
* init.el
ComplexObjectFactory.java
some-elisp.el
AnotherFile.txt
<more_files_here>
```

When I hit my keybind for `next-buffer`:

```
HelloWorld.txt
* App.js
init.el
ComplexObjectFactory.java
some-elisp.el
AnotherFile.txt
<more_files_here>
```

When I hit my keybind for `previous-buffer` x4:

```
HelloWorld.txt
App.js
init.el
ComplexObjectFactory.java
some-elisp.el
* AnotherFile.txt
<more_files_here>
```

When I hit my keybind for `next-buffer` x2:

```
HelloWorld.txt
App.js
init.el
* ComplexObjectFactory.java
some-elisp.el
AnotherFile.txt
<more_files_here>
```

When I hit my keybind for `previous-buffer` x4:

```
* HelloWorld.txt
App.js
init.el
ComplexObjectFactory.java
some-elisp.el
AnotherFile.txt
<more_files_here>
```

When I switch buffers via C-x b, the selected buffer is inserted into current position of the current buffer and the current buffer becomes the previous the buffer (the rest are shifted back/down)  but all of the "next buffers" stay the same.
When I open a new file as a buffer, the same type of behavior happens.

Essentially, the buffer list order is maintained with respect to the originally opened order of buffers and only changed by adding more recently opened/selected buffers as the previous buffers of the current buffer but leaving the next buffers untouched (except when one of them would now become a previous buffer).

If that makes any sense. How would I go about getting this kind of functionality/workflow? I have looked at the `previous-buffer` and `next-buffer` functions inside of `window.el` but the issue is that the logic for `switch-to-prev-buffer` and `switch-to-next-buffer` is so unimaginably complex for what I would expect to be a simple piece of functionality. It appears that everything is so deeply intertwined for buffers, windows, and files that I honestly don't know how to untangle the spaghetti. I would have imagined this might even be a configurable setting but no luck finding anything. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: The global buffer-list and frame buffer-list cannot entirely be controlled by the user.  To have entire control over a list of buffers, it would be necessary to create a different list and manage it separately.  Alp Aker uses a unique approach with his frame-bufs library, but that is just an example of how to manage a separate buffer list that can be controlled by the user.

Comment: In your last example, I think you mean `next-buffer x3` - yes?

Comment: @NickD Actually, I meant `previous-buffer x4` as it should wrap around. I fixed that with an edit now. Good catch.

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on how many files are in `<more_files_here>`?

Comment: @NickD Technically, yes, it would. However, for brevity, I just assumed it is a single file in the example at that point ... but yes, it would be `previous-buffer xN + 1` where `N = the number of buffers represented by "<more_files_here>"` for the proper wrap around formula. Does that help clarify things? Sorry about that over simplification.